# Duplicate list in list of list

Tags: python, pandas, list, duplicates

I want to duplicate a list in a list of list with header. The list of list is coming from a `list =[pandas.read_excel(file, header=['a','b']) for file in files]` to read multiple excel files.

So I have `list = [[first_list], [second_list], [third_list], ...]`
All the lists have the same header.

I want to duplicate the second list (and only this one) to have :

```
list = [[first_list], [second_list], [second_list], [third_list], ...]
```

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list with at least 2 elements called `my_list`, you can do:

```py
my_list.insert(2, my_list[1])
```